# Save image from Image.Control to website directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to save an image from a .net Image Control to the server's directory?

It's a barcode image that gets generated on Page_Load:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/app/barcode.aspx?code=TEST"
```

The barcode image displays just fine on the webpage, but I wnated to save it to a directory as well:

`~/barcode image/TEST.jpg`

---

So far, here's what I have:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string remote = Server.MapPath("..") + @"\app\barcode.aspx?code=TEST";
string local = Server.MapPath("..") + @"\barcode image\TEST.jpg";
webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);
```

But it gives me an error: `Illegal characters in path.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebClient` requires a web address for the remote parameter - you are giving it a *local* path for this parameter.

Additionally `Server.MapPath` expects a proper directory - not `..`.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string remote = @"http://localhost/app/barcode.aspx?code=TEST";
string local = Server.MapPath("barcode image/TEST.jpg");
webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);
```

Comment: oded - should I hardcode this? @"http://localhost... because I got an error: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: @PodMays - I don't know the name of your web server. You can get this from the Http headers instead.

Comment: oded I was able to get the path through: `remote = @"http://" + Request.Url.Authority.ToString()+ @"/app/BarCode.aspx?code=TEST"` but it still gives me the error. `An exception occurred during a WebClient request.`

Comment: @PodMays - What exception? What are the details? Actually looking at those, you may get a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: This is all that it says: `An exception occurred during a WebClient request`. I'm still not sure what's the problem. The code looks like this in the debugger: `webClient.DownloadFile("http://localhost:6585/app/BarCode.aspx?code=test", "C:\\test.jpg")`

Comment: @PodMays - Why are you not debugging through to get the full exception details?